# getName() vs Thread.currentThread().getName(). Please explain difference between these two

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

```
public class SynchThread1 extends Thread {
    SynchThread1 st;
    SynchThread1() {}
    SynchThread1(SynchThread1 s) {
        st = s;
    }
    public void run() {
        st.show();
    }
    synchronized void show() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " "); //replace here
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SynchThread1 s1 = new SynchThread1();
        Thread t1 = new SynchThread1(s1);
        Thread t2 = new SynchThread1(s1);
        Thread t3 = new SynchThread1(s1);
        s1.setName("t0");
        t1.setName("t1");
        t2.setName("t2");
        t3.setName("t3");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }
}
```

Output of above code is:

```
t1 t1 t1 t1 t1 t3 t3 t3 t3 t3 t2 t2 t2 t2 t2
```

but if I replace `Thread.currentThread().getName()` with `getName()` only, the output is:

```
t0 t0 t0 t0 t0 t0 t0 t0 t0 t0 t0 t0 t0 t0 t0
```

Please explain why this is happening.

Comment: Because you are messing around with threads, mixing up threads and tasks (Runnables).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Thread.currentThread().getName()` gets you the name of the currently-running thread, but `getName()` resolves to `st.getName()`, and `st` is always your first thread instance.

Why does `getName()` resolve to `st.getName()`? Because:

1. During construction of your second through fourth threads, you pass the first thread in as an argument and save it in the instance member `st`.
2. The `run` method of your threads calls `st.show()`, so they're always calling `show` on the first thread. (If you ever started the first thread, you'd get an NPE there, since the first thread's `st` member is never given a non-`null` value.)
3. Within `show`, `this` is therefore `st` (the first thread). Unqualified instance method calls use `this` as their instance, and `this` is the first thread.